# How can I work with embedded youtube videos with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a youtube player that changes videos when the links on the right are clicked. I know this is pretty basic but I've been tearing my hair out for 3 days now. I found an example using pictures an have been trying to modify it but no luck. Please help!

[video gallery](http://www.outoffocus.tv/gallery.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to jQuery and try this:

http://smple.com/videoGallery/

Of course there are plenty alternatives available. Please see:
http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/multimedia-jquery-plugins/best-jquery-video-plugins/